# Java Thread sleep issue

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, delay, wait

I'm having some trouble with making a short delay in my program. All I want is for the system to stop for about 1 second after some text is set but for some reason it won't let me set some text, delay, and then run more code. It just seems to ignore the code before it and just execute the following code.

```
if (event.getSource() == btnAnswer){

            if (userAnswer.equals(questions[x].correctAnswers)){
                lblQuestion.setText("Correct!");
            }
            else{
                lblQuestion.setText("Incorrect.");
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            userAnswer = "";

            turn +=1;
            if (turn > numOfPlayers){
                turn = 1;
            }
            lblTurn.setText(playerNames[turn] + "'s turn:");

            x = rand.nextInt(9);
            //loop stops questions from being the same one after another
            while (x == prev){
                x = rand.nextInt(9);
            }
            prev = x;

            lblQuestion.setText(questions[x].question);
```

etc...

The temporary text set is not even shown.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This is a fairly common problem, and a search like [this one](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=thread.sleep+swing+delay+java+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F) (click on the link) would probably work well in your situation. [Here's another useful search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+delay), one that uses the search engine on this site.

Comment: The issue is that your call to `Thread.sleep` puts the Swing event thread, and thus your GUI to sleep, so nothing gets painted, no interactions occur. You need to avoid stepping on the Swing event thread when trying to introduce a delay, and the easiest way to do this is to use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), but again the two searches above will tell you all this and show you example code too.